# Add SQL PHP array to an already existing array

Tags: php, sql, json, foreach, while-loop

I have two database tables.  One contains Marketplaces and the other contains the Locations of the Marketplaces.  Marketplaces can have multiple locations the two tables are joined by the MarketplaceID. I need to query the marketplaces turn it into an array and during the foreach or the while, add the locations as an array to the marketplaces. This is all part of two json responses. However my goal is to combine the data together and have one json response where the locations are within the marketplaces json data as "Locations". Ultimately an array where Marketplaces is the parent and Locations are the children.

Code 1 (Table1 Query):

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM Marketplaces WHERE Status = 1";
$result = mysql_query($sql);

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){   
  foreach($row as $key => $value){
      $arr[$key] = $value;
  }
  $main_arr[] = $arr;
}
return $main_arr;
```

Result:

```
[{"MarketplaceID":"1","AccountID":"0","BusinessName":"Mike's Pub","BusinessType":"1","Status":"1","CreationDate":"0000-00-00 00:00:00"}]
```

Code 2 (Table2 Query):

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM Locations WHERE MarketplaceID = 1";
$results = mysql_query($sql);

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($results)){
  foreach($row as $key => $value){
    $arr[$key]=$value;
  }
  $main_arr[] = $arr;
}
```

Result:

```
[{"LocationID":"1","MarketplaceID":"1","Address1":"5055 Business Center Drive","Address2":"Suite 100","City":"San Francisco","CA":"1","Zip":"90210","Phone1":"(555) 555-555","Phone2":"(555) 555-5555","EmailAddress":"email@msn.com","StoreNumber":"200"},{"LocationID":"2","MarketplaceID":"1","Address1":"112 Street Court","Address2":"","City":"Los Angeles","StateID":"2","Zip":"90210","Phone1":"(555) 555-6666","Phone2":"","EmailAddress":"email@gmail.com","StoreNumber":"300"}]
```

Comment: What do you want the combined result to look like?

Comment: First of all, you need to think about why you've done this: `$row = mysql_fetch_assoc(..)` then foreach `$row` to create **exactly** the same array under a different name `$arr`

Comment: Why are you creating an array in Code 1? There can only be one marketplace with ID = 1.

Comment: @Barmar they are two different queries..  I want my results to contain all the locations in one array, rather than two separate arrays that are currently split by two different logics, that I also want to comibine.

Comment: Can you post *in the question* how you want the results to look.

Comment: Preferably indented nicely so we can see the structure, not all on one line.

Comment: @trapper then you have to explain how to get that in an array where Marketplaces is the parent and Locations the children

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, drop this

```
  foreach($row as $key => $value){
      $arr[$key] = $value;
  }
```

It does nothing except the same as `$arr = $row`; Actually it does something else - produces a warning as `$arr` is undefined.

**EDIT** Updated answer now that the initial query has been changed from `WHERE MarketplaceID=1` to `WHERE 
Status = 1"`

```
$main_arr=array();
$sql = "SELECT * FROM Marketplaces WHERE Status = 1";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){   
  $row['locations']=array();
  $sql2 = "SELECT * FROM Locations WHERE MarketplaceID = ".$row['MarketplaceID'];
  $results2 = mysql_query($sql2);
  while($row2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($results2)){
      $row['locations'][]=$row2;
  }
  $main_arr[] = $row; 
}

// print_r($main_arr); and view page source to read, rather than a JSON string
```

Actually I would do this slightly differently so that my array doesn't muddle locations inside of Marketplace but still keeps them together, like this below

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){   
  $thisrow=array('marketplace'=>$row, 'locations'=>array());
  $sql2 = "SELECT * FROM Locations WHERE MarketplaceID = ".$row['MarketplaceID'];
  $results2 = mysql_query($sql2);
  while($row2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($results2)){
      $thisrow['locations'][]=$row2;
  }
  $main_arr[] = $thisrow; 
}
```

so the object would be

```
{ 
    "marketplace": {"MarketplaceID": 1, "BusinessName": "Fred Bloggs", ... }
    "locations": [
        {"LocationId": 1, "Address1": "Some address"},
        {"LocationId": 2, "Address1": "Some address"}
    ]
}
```

Comment: can I pass the MarketplaceID into the second query.  I tried this and did not work: $sql = "SELECT * FROM Locations WHERE MarketplaceID = '".$marketplace['MarketplaceID']."'";

Comment: I apologize for the confusion and trying to simplify in order to make it easier, but this has just made it tuffer =P.  I now understand a bit more how you saw everything and you saw the big picture without me explaining.  The first query is updated to this (more than 1 location):

$sql = "SELECT * FROM Marketplaces WHERE Status = 1";

and the second

$sql = "SELECT * FROM Locations WHERE MarketplaceID = '".$marketplace['MarketplaceID']."'";

How can I add the for each back to make this work?

Comment: ok. I've just added an addendum as to how I would actually do this, having thought about it.

Comment: Keeping the same logic you are familiar with.  If I were to add Programs as a child to Locations and Rewards as a child to Programs.  How would I handle that? Here is my code that is NOT nesting in the HTML section: http://jsfiddle.net/rHgS3/ @phpnoodles

Comment: What you've written ins close but you need to be creating arrays within the arrays not adding to $row, e.g. `$row['locations']['programs']=array();` `$row['locations']['programs'][]=$row3;`, `$row['locations']['programs']['rewards']=array();` `$row['locations']['programs']['rewards'][]=$row4;`

Answer (score 0):

If I'm reading it correctly, your first array is a single dimension array that houses the Marketplace 1 data, and your second array is a multidimensional array where each element in the parent array contains a child array which contains information about a single location.  If you want to place the second array within the first, try nesting your loops like this:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM Marketplaces WHERE MarketplaceID = 1";
$result = mysql_query($sql);

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){   

  foreach($row as $key => $value){
  $arr[$key] = $value;

}

$sql2 = "SELECT * FROM Locations WHERE MarketplaceID = 1";
$results2 = mysql_query($sql2);

while($row2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($results2)){

  foreach($row2 as $key => $value){
  $arr2[$key]=$value;

}

$arr['locations'] = $arr2;

$main_arr = $arr;

}
```

This creates a temporary array, $arr2, that houses your location data, and then stores it in $arr['locations'].  At the end of the code, the $arr that you're adding to $main_arr should have the following elements: "MarketplaceID","AccountID","BusinessName","BusinessType","Status","CreationDate","location", and "location" should be an array containing elements as arrays containing the location information pulled from your database.

Hope this answers your question.